# How to pass strings from a vector to the C++ remove function?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a C++ program that tries to execute the `ls` command and then tries to store the names of the files in a `vector` like this:

```
vector<char *> exec(const char *cmd)
{
    int count = 0;
    char buffer[128];
    vector<char *> result;
    FILE *pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe)
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    try
    {
        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pipe) != NULL)
        {
            count++;
            result.push_back(buffer);
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        pclose(pipe);
        throw;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

Then  try to delete these files by using them in another function:

```
void nuke_folder()
{
    vector<char *> files = exec(LIST_DIR);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << files[i] << endl;
        if (remove(files[i]) != 0)

            perror("Error deleting file");
    }
}
```

But `nuke_folder` does not do anything to the files, how can I remove the files by passing strings from the vector?

Comment: i think you have to specify the correct path where files are located like `~/Desktop/dir_name` + `file_name` to `remove` function. Can you specify the argument to `ls` command?

Comment: Perhaps as a side note, if this is part of some larger code that needs to work with the filesystem, I would suggest looking into [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem), which is supported on most newer compiler releases (requires C++17 support).

Comment: @Qubit it does not work with my version of `g++` (4.9)

Comment: You may have to use `std::experimental::filesystem` on some older versions of g++. But I think 4.9 might not even have that yet (I did not check thoroughly).

Comment: @nietzsche `result.push_back(buffer);` -- This will not work, as you are storing the address of a local variable.  Why not use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `std::vector<char *>`?